# jquery popup not opening with rest of website script

Tags: jquery, facebook, popup

I am trying to integrate a facebook login into my website, using the following code in my header file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.bitandpiecesvape.co.uk/site/library/facebook/js/oauthpopup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#facebookLogin').click(function(e){
        $.oauthpopup({
            path: 'http://www.bitandpiecesvape.co.uk/site/library/facebook/login.php',
            width:600,
            height:300,
            callback: function(){
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

And this at the top of the body tag

```
<img src="http://www.bitandpiecesvape.co.uk/site/library/facebook/images/facebook.png" id="facebookLogin" style="cursor:pointer;" />
```

This works fine if I place a php exit; afterwards. But as soon as I remove this, the pop up no longer works.

There must be something clashing in the code and I cannot figure out what. I don't have much experience with JQuery. I am running ZURB Foundation, but I have tried removing this JQuery and it does not help the situation.

How can I find out what is clashing and how to fix it?

Thank you,
Tom

Comment: any error showing on `console`

Comment: Ive actually never used a javascript console. Thanks for pointing me to it, I obviously need to fix a few things. Anyway - it says "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" :-S On line 76 of index. Index.php ends on line 75

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function(index):76 (anonymous function)jquery.min.js:2 p.event.dispatchjquery.min.js:2 p.event.add.g.handle.h

Comment: which version of `jQuery` your using

Comment: I found a clash. I am using 1.11.2 in the header but found I was calling for 1.8.2 in a sub file. What version would you suggest?

Comment: most of the time i use `1.9.1` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for your help Amit! The console lead me to find that I was trying to include jQuery 1.8.2 in one of my other files, as well as trying to get version 1.11.2 on the header file. I removed the 1.8.2 and it works fine. +1 for google chrome's developer tools.